# Sources de phonétique française

Tags: ressources, phonétique

Les anglophones ont des grammaires anglaises pour ceux qui apprennent une langue étrangère. Moi je cherche des sources de phonétique française pour la même raison.

J'ai vu par exemple des livres s'adressant explicitement à des étrangers (FLE), d'autres pour orthophonistes, certains à connotation historique, etc. Je ne sais pas à quel point ils se ressemblent.

Comment: I used Phonétique française by  Bertil Malmberg and it's pretty good, it has a lot of examples and it explains how to articulate things clearly. It's great for beginners.

Comment: Un manuel pour orthophoniste ne traitera que des problèmes spécifiques à la correction des natifs, et les problèmes sont différents pour un non natif qui apprend la langue. Ensuite il faut savoir si c'est pour ta propre amélioration en tant que francophone ou dans un but d'apprentissage à un non natif (auquel cas [celui-ci](https://laprononciationenclasse.jimdo.com/), et peut-être des pistes sur [Le Point du FLE](https://www.lepointdufle.net/penseigner/phonetique-fiches-pedagogiques.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Si vous aimez l'histoire de la langue ou simplement les vieux livres, il existe le *Dictionnaire phonétique de la langue française, complément nécessaire de tout dictionnaire français*, d’Hermann Michaelis, publié en 1914 chez Carl Meyer Verlag (lisible sur [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/dictionnairephon00michuoft/page/n7/mode/2up)).
Il présente selon un classement alphabétique la transcription phonétique des mots français tels qu'ils se prononcent dans  « la population cultivée du Nord de la France » (p. VIII) à cette époque.

Answer (score 0):

French dictionnary Larousse has a voice set of every term : https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais.

(I'm not sure if I'm answering your question.)

Answer (score 0):

Je ne sais pas sous quelle forme tu les cherches. En tout cas le TiLF comprend la prononciation des mots:

http://atilf.atilf.fr/

Pour plus de ressources lexicographiques, on se réfèrera au CNRTL:

https://www.cnrtl.fr/portail/